# Permissions needed to query sys.objects for sequence created by the same user

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

NOTE: I have checked this question and answer and it did not answer my use case: [Permission for querying dbo.sysobjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356287/permission-for-querying-dbo-sysobjects)

I have the following stored procedure to create a sequence if it does not exist:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE seq.CreateSequenceIfNotExists 
    @FullSequenceName nvarchar(500)
WITH EXECUTE AS 'SequenceCreator'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        
    IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM sys.objects
                    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@FullSequenceName) AND type = 'SO'))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SequenceCreateSql NVARCHAR(700)
        SET @SequenceCreateSql = CONCAT('CREATE SEQUENCE ', @FullSequenceName, 'START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NO CACHE')
        EXEC sp_executesql @stmnt = @SequenceCreateSql
    END
END
GO
```

The user it runs as (`SequenceCreator`) has ONLY the following permission:

```
GRANT CREATE SEQUENCE ON SCHEMA::seq TO SequenceCreator  
GO
```

When this stored procedure runs, it works fine to create the sequence.  But when I run it a second time, the query to `sys.objects` returns no rows and it tries to create a the sequence again (it returns one row when I run it as `dbo` (as expected)).

I assume that the user `SequenceCreator` does not have the permissions to query this row in `sys.objects`.

What are the minimum permissions needed to allow this user to check for the existence of sequences that it creates?

(NOTE: I need it to be the "**minimum** permissions", because I cannot parameterize the name of the sequence, so it could be hit with a SQL injection attack. Though unlikely in my use case, I need the user to not have any real permissions to exploit)

Comment: What user owns the `seq` schema? You could `GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::seq TO SequenceCreator;`, which will proved meta-data visibility. Personally, I would avoid `EXECUTE AS` and instead sign the proc based on a certificate user with the needed permissions. That way, you only need to grant exec permissions on the proc to users that need that ability.

Comment: @DanGuzman - Right now `dbo` owns the schema `seq`.  (I can change that if needed).  I like the `VIEW DEFINITION` option, I will look into that.  I was planning to do similar to what you outline with the certificate user with my SQL User without a login, but I will look into what you suggest for added security.